# Get, alter and update the copy cache

Tags: c#, caching, .net-4.0

I searched pretty much everywhere on google, but I didn't find anything useable. I want to know how to get the current cache and save it on a string. This string will get processed and afterwards replace the current cache.

I am talking about our ordinary copy cache (CTRL + C) on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e.aspx

Example from MSDN:

```
// Demonstrates SetText, ContainsText, and GetText.
public String SwapClipboardHtmlText(String replacementHtmlText)
{
    String returnHtmlText = null;
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
    {
        returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
        Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
    }
    return returnHtmlText;
}
```

Comment: I'm working with a console-app, I can't add System.Windows.Forms to that :/

Comment: Why not? Simply add a Reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: You need to 'Add Reference' to the System.Windows.Forms.dll. Do this by right clicking on your project and choosing 'Add Reference', then find the System.Windows.Forms component and add it to your project.

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer if it answered your question?

Comment: Ye, I always do that, I just had to make sure it all works in the end. Thank you, it worked brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

First in your console application add reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` via the Solution Explorer window. Then you should be able to add `using System.Windows.Forms`.

Here is some sample code to read clipboard text from your console application (**important** : you need the [STAThread] attribute added to your Main as shown below; else there will be a `ThreadStateException` thrown)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
            {
                string clipBoardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
                Console.WriteLine("TEXT in ClipBoard : " + clipBoardText);

                Console.WriteLine("Type text to replace (and press Enter key) :");
                string replaceText = Console.ReadLine();
                Clipboard.SetText(replaceText);
                Console.WriteLine("REPLACED ClipBoard Text : " + Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text));               
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No text in clipboard, please type now (and press Enter key) :");
                string newText = Console.ReadLine();
                Clipboard.SetText(newText);
                Console.WriteLine("NEW ClipBoard Text : " + Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text));    
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```